# error in sending transaction USDT(TRC-20)

Tags: python, transactions, web3py

can't send USDT transaction in network trc-20 produces the following error response

```
{
 "result": {
 "code": "OTHER_ERROR",
 "message": "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"}}
```

in my project i use TronGridApi
here is my transaction send code:

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode

private_key = "my_private_key"
sender_address = "TM72pHE4UynHgYnVPBtgp3o18qygX7zqFF"
recipient_address = "THUNG82XB4G5knZ52W5V88FZZhcyHDzHib"
amount = 3 * 10**6  # amount of USDT (in sng)

contract_address = "TA1EHWb1PymZ1qpBNfNj9uX8X5U5pPZ5r6"

# Create a transaction
trigger_smart_contract_url = "https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/triggersmartcontract"
transaction = {
"owner_address": sender_address,
"contract_address": contract_address,
"function_selector": "transfer(address,uint256)",
"parameter": f"{recipient_address[2:].lower():0>64}{hex(amount)[2:].lower():0>64}",
"fee_limit": 1000000,
"call_value": 0
}

encoded_transaction = urlencode(transaction)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response = requests.post(trigger_smart_contract_url, data=encoded_transaction, 
headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    transaction_data = response.json()
else:
    print(f"Ошибка при создании транзакции (HTTP {response.status_code}):")
    print(response.text)
    exit()

if 'transaction' in transaction_data:
    unsigned_transaction = transaction_data['transaction']
else:
   print("Ошибка при создании транзакции:")
   print(json.dumps(transaction_data, indent=2))
   exit()

# Transaction signature
sign_url = "https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactionsign"
response = requests.post(sign_url, json={"transaction": unsigned_transaction, 
"privateKey": private_key})
signed_transaction = response.json()

# Send signed transaction
broadcast_url = "https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/broadcasttransaction"
response = requests.post(broadcast_url, json=signed_transaction)
transaction_result = response.json()

print("Транзакция отправлена:")
print(json.dumps(transaction_result, indent=2))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use third-party libraries in the project, since they do not work with the web3 library.